# How can i read data from Elasticsearch using spark (Eclipse) and convert it into tabular format

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop

I have successfully pushed a csv file into my elasticsearch .

```
val spark=SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("eswithfunctions")
  .config("spark.master","local")
  .config("spark.es.nodes","localhost")
  .config("spark.es.port","9200")
  .getOrCreate()

  println("Enter path of file saved locally")
  val path=scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
  val dataframe=spark.read
  .option("inferSchema", "true").csv(path)

  println("Enter the name you want to save dataframe in Elasticsearch")
   val index=scala.io.StdIn.readLine()  
   dataframe.saveToEs(index-name)
```

How do i read the same from elasticseach server and see the result in tabular format in spark.

Comment: Could you please update a sample document which you pushed into Elasticsearch? Also if you can share its mapping, I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually specify the data source that will be used along with any extra options that you would like to pass to the data source. Data sources are specified by their fully qualified name (i.e., org.apache.spark.sql.parquet), but for built-in sources, you can also use their short names (json, parquet, jdbc, orc, libsvm, csv, text). DataFrames loaded from any data source type can be converted into other types using this syntax.

To load a JSON file you can use:

```
val peopleDF = spark.read.format("json").load("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
peopleDF.select("name", "age").write.format("parquet").save("namesAndAges.parquet")
```

More info about spark [Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html).